# Mail not working - IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-14.04, ipv6, apache2.4

We are having trouble to sent out mails.

We are trying to sent out via SSH to test:

```
(echo: subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -Am -i info@example.com
```

But get error:

`[2a01:7e01::f03c:91ff:febb:bbe2]` Our system has detected that this
message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records
and authentication.

We have set the reverse DNS to from SERVER_IP to target: example.com

What are we missing here for it to be able to sent out mails?

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I would start...

I would first make sure that my file /etc/hosts contains my ipv4 address and server name like this (replace everything in quotes, do not include quotes)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
"server ip"  "yourServerName"."yourDomain.com"  "yourServerName"
```

"yourDomain.com" is the address that your A record points to in your DNS settings.

To set "yourServerName", open /etc/hostname and change whatever is there to "yourServerName". Then reboot server.